# Drupal 7 - how do I create a custom registration form

Tags: drupal-7, user-registration, drupal-hooks

I am new to Drupal development. I want to create a registration form for visitors of my site. Default registration page only has two fields: Username and Email address.

1. How can I add more fields to it, e.g password, picture and timezone. I also want to capture tow other information - Date of Birth and Gender. These two fields are not available in default `users` table. How can I tie these information with a user account? Do I have to create a new table and put these information there referencing the `uid` of `user` table? If it is possible how can I pull the joined record?
2. Is there any possibility that I create a new content type for this purpose but records still go to default `users` table and can be used for login?
3. If 2 above is not possible I probably have to use `hook_form_alter` but where should I put this function?
4. When creating a custom registration form shall I use default registration page i.e. /user/register and customize it?

I am sorry if above questions look very childish and silly! Hope you will consider my my newbie status. If possible please help me with a step by step solution.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

To accomplish the requirement I created a custom module called `user_signup` and in `user_signup.module` file I have written the following code.

```html
<?php
/*
Implements hook_menu()
*/

function user_signup_menu(){
  $items = array();
 $items['user/signup'] = array(
  'title' => 'Sign Up',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('user_signup_registration_page'),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
 );
  return $items;
}

function user_signup_registration_page($form, &$form_state){
  $form['name'] = array(
        '#title' => 'Username',
        '#description' => 'choose a username',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['mail'] = array(
        '#title' => 'Email',
        '#description' => 'enter a valid email address',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['pass'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Password',
      '#description' => 'Enter a strong password',
      '#type' => 'password',
      '#required' => TRUE
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Create Account'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function user_signup_registration_page_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $new_user_id = db_insert('users')
    ->$fields(array( **//this is line number 45**
      'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
      'mail' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
      'pass' => $form_state['values']['pass'],
    ))
    ->execute();

    drupal_set_message(t('New user created'));
}
```

Everything works perfectly but when I hit the submit button I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Method name must be a string in D:\xampp\htdocs\imdbind\sites\all\modules\user-signup\user_signup.module on line 45

I have marked **line number 45** in above code snippet as `**//this is line number 45**`. I did not find any difference when comparing my code with theirs. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change line 45 with following
From:

```
    ->$fields(array( **//this is line number 45**
```

To

```
    ->fields(array( **//this is line number 45**
```

Comment: Wow! what a mistake. Thanks so much for correcting :) However I have to pass a value for column `uid` in `users` table. I just checked the structure and it doesn't seem to be an auto incremental field. Question is if I change the filed to auto incremental will this create problem for rest of the site?

Comment: Nope, I guess users table does not have dependencies on any other tables in drupal database. Go ahead and do that. Before that take complete DB backup

Answer (score 1):

You can add Fields here /admin/config/people/accounts/fields int eh People Account settings Manage Fields form.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am now trying to actually use a custom module and store user registration data from there. Everything seems to be working OK only before I hit `Submit`! I have updated my question with the code I have written in `user_signup.module` file. What's wrong in my code?